# Rails 4.2.6 generator model. Inherit from other class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Now, when I run `rails g model foo` I get

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord:Base
end
```

and I want to get like

```
class Foo < AbstractModel
end
```

**UPDATE**

The possible way is to update `model_generator.rb` with:

```
require 'rails/generators/active_record'

module ActiveRecord
  module Generators # :nodoc:
    class ModelGenerator < Base # :nodoc:
      ...
      protected

      def parent_class_name
        options[:parent] || "AbstractModel"
      end

    end
  end
end
```

May be this is not the best solution, but it works. You know better?

Comment: whats your other class name ?

Comment: class name is AbstractModel

Answer (score 1):

Rails will generate you based on `ActiveRecord`

after ran: `rails g model foo`

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord:Base
end
```

Change `ActiveRecord:Base` to name of your class, to inherit it.

or

need to run `rails g model foo --parent abstract_model`

```
class Foo < AbstractModel
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know, how to inherit class. The question is how to config generator

Comment: Mine too ;) I've found this monkey patch useful. entering parent every time was too long. I think I was not full enough in my question. Sorry